# Returning values form OnSensorChanged() method

Tags: android, return, proximity

What I'd like to achieve is to return the correct result set in method `isClose`. The problem is the`isClose` method is not waiting for `onSensorChanged` to be triggered and returns the default "0" value of `isClose` field.

I call my Position class like this:
       `Position mPosition = new Position();`

`boolean result = mPosition.isInPocket(this);`

Position class:

```
public class Position implements SensorEventListener {

  private SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private Sensor mProximity;
  private boolean isClose;

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] value = event.values;


    if(value[0] > 0)    {
        isClose = false;
    }   else
                {
          isClose = true;
    }   
}

public boolean isClose(Context context) {

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, 0);


    return isClose; // I'd like to return this with value set in onSensorChanged. 
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have your main thread `wait` in `isClose` for the first `onSensorChanged` event, you can achieve this in many ways, but using a [`Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) variable would probably be the easiest.

```
public class Position implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mProximity;
    private boolean isClose;
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition eventReceived = lock.newCondition();
    private boolean firstEventOccurred = false;

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float[] value = event.values;


        if (value[0] > 0)    {
            isClose = false;
        }   else {
            isClose = true;
        }
        if (!firstEventOccurred) {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                firstEventOccurred = true;
                eventReceived.signal();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isClose(Context context) {

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, 0);

        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!firstEventOccurred) {
                eventReceived.await();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return isClose; // I'd like to return this with value set in onSensorChanged. 
    }
```

I've omitted `InterrupedException` checks from the above code, but it should give you an idea.